# How to justify text in label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, text-alignment

In Tkinter in Python:
I have a table with a different label. How can I justify the text that is in the label? Because It is a table and the texts in different labels come together!

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
a=Label(root,text='Hello World!')
a.pack()
a.place(x=200,y=200)
b=Label(root,text='Bye World')
b.pack()
b.place(x=200,y=100)
```

I want something for justifying in center some text in label but it is not something that I need plz check this: [link](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00778/5p8kfr6qjgx3.png)

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: There's no point in calling `pack` if you're calling `place` immediately after. Only one will have an effect, and it's always the last one you call.

Answer (score 48):

By default, the text in a label is centered. You can control this with the `anchor` attribute, and possibly with the `justify` attribute. `justify` only affects the text when there is more than one line of text in the widget.

For example, to get the text inside a label to be right-aligned you can use `anchor="e"` (which stands for "east"):

```
a=Label(root,text='Hello World!', anchor="e")
```

Note, however, this will appear to have no effect if the label is exactly big enough to hold the text. In your specific example, you would need to give each label the same width:

```
a=Label(..., width=12)
b=Label(..., width=12)
```

Comment: for other anchor options: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm

Comment: just to say, this whole East West terminology (e, w, se) is a tad pretentious and unnecessary. Would rather it was Top Left etc. Wish tkinter was more practical and intuitive in this respect. Just airing some griefs :)

Answer (score 15):

To add on to what Bryan said, `LEFT` is the constant you are looking for to correctly format your wrapped text. You can also justify to the `RIGHT` or `CENTER` (the default).

```
a=Label(root,text='Hello World!', anchor="e", justify=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 10):

instead of using .pack() i would use .grid()

[The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112011230/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

grid will allow better management of your components

find bellow an example of usage and management:

```
Label(root, text="First").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Second").grid(row=1, sticky=W)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

checkbutton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

image.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
           sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)

button1.grid(row=2, column=2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=3)
```

you would endup using the grid option padx="x"  to "justify" your labels

Comment: I want something for justifying in center some text in label but it is not something that I need 
plz check this  :

[link](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00778/5p8kfr6qjgx3.png)

Comment: as mentioned, using grid, and option padx="pixels", please review http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm you will find what you need there

Comment: re _"instead of using pack() I would use grid()"_ - they aren't using `pack`, they are using `place`. They _attempt_ to use `pack`, but when you call `place` immediately after it removes any effect that `pack` had.

Comment: I think you meant `entry2 = Entry(root)` and not `entry1 = Entry(root)` 2 times in a row.