# Why justify and anchor do not work for Label of Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, label

I am using following code and trying to center the text on labels:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
llist = ["first:","second label:","a really long label:","fourth:","fifth:"]
nrow = 0
for i in range(len(llist)):
    # Label(root, text=llist[i], justify='right').grid(row=nrow, column=0) # does not work
    # Label(root, text=llist[i], justify=RIGHT).grid(row=nrow, column=0) # does not work
    # Label(root, text=llist[i], anchor=E).grid(row=nrow, column=0) # does not work
    # Label(root, text=llist[i], anchor=E, justify=RIGHT).grid(row=nrow, column=0) # does not work
    Label(root, text=llist[i]).grid(row=nrow, column=0, sticky=E) # WORKS; 
    Entry(root).grid(row=nrow, column=1)
    nrow += 1
root.mainloop()
```

The text remains in `center` with options that I mention as not working in above code:

[image]

Only with `sticky` option in the `grid()` it works properly:

[image]

Why `justify` and `anchor` options of `Label` do not work in above code, even though they are mentioned at several places such as http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm ? How can `justify` and `anchor` be used to align text in Labels?

Comment: The problem is probably that when the widget is fit, its text's justification can be considered _anything_ as there's no space to align to. By default widgets are fit.

Comment: How are justify and anchor to be used?

Comment: The way second image works is that it first crops as much space needed for the Label, and then puts it to the east of the first column. With justify you should occupy the first column entirely with the Label widget, and simply move its text with justify option inside the label widget. Perhaps add `bg='red'` option to better see what space the Label occupies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to justify text in label in tkinter in python Need justify in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318060/how-to-justify-text-in-label-in-tkinter-in-python-need-justify-in-tkinter)

Comment: Add `background="pink"` to your labels. You'll be able to better visualize what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you haven't set `width` for `Label`, if you don't set it, `Label` will fit its content. So in short, the text inside `Label` is worked with `anchor` option, but `Label`'s length is the same as text's length. And what located at `center` is not `text` but `Label`.

If you manually set a width for it:

```
Label(root, text=llist[i], anchor="e", width=20).grid(row=nrow, column=0)
```

It will work, but it is difficult to manually specify the length of `Label`, so use `grid`'s `sticky` option is much better.

Comment: What does "it is difficult to manually specify the length of `Label`" mean? Why is it difficult?

Comment: @BryanOakley Because in most of complicated cases, you cannot decide width easily. In this simple case, surely you can set width to `max([len(text) for text in llist])`