# "Justify=LEFT" NOT WORKING on Tkinter Label Widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So, I have `tkinter` labels and I want the text within them to be `left aligned`. I am using `justify=LEFT` but it isn't working. I can't figure out why?

This is the code for my Label Widget:

```
Label(displayWindow, text=value, width=15, borderwidth=3, justify=LEFT, relief=GROOVE, font=("times",13,"bold"), bg="lightblue").grid(row=row_num+1,column=col, padx=5, sticky=EW)
```

This is the output:
[image]

**NOTE:** *How the contents in column `First Name` and `Last Name` are not `LEFT` aligned they are still `CENTER` aligned.*

Comment: Use `anchor='w'` instead of `justify=LEFT` as justify is used for wrapping of multiple lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-justify-text-in-label-in-tkinter-in-python-need-justify-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318060)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `justify` option only comes into play when the text wraps to multiple lines. You need to use the `anchor` option if you want the text to be at the left edge of the widget.

```
Label(..., anchor="w")
```

From the [canonical tcl/tk man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm):

**anchor** - Specifies how the information in a widget (e.g. text or a bitmap) is to be displayed in the widget. Must be one of the values **n**, **ne**, **e**, **se**, **s**, **sw**, **w**, **nw**, or **center**. For example, **nw** means display the information such that its top-left corner is at the top-left corner of the widget.

**justify** - When there are multiple lines of text displayed in a widget, this option determines how the lines line up with each other. Must be one of **left**, **center**, or **right**. **Left** means that the lines' left edges all line up, **center** means that the lines' centers are aligned, and **right** means that the lines' right edges line up.