# How to control label positions and spacing in Tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

Now I want to make the food price at the same row therefore I change that to row 2 as well but then the output is this

the food goes back to row 0, why does it do that? I am trying to get something like this:

```
foodprice=['3','2','1.50']
drinks = ['Water','Hot water','Medium water']
drinksprice = ['1','2','3']

myFrame3 = Frame(root, bg = '')
myFrame3.pack()

myFrame3.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame3.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

for x in range (len(food)):
    foodop = Label(myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = food[x])
    foodop.grid(row = 2+x, column = 4) # <--
for x in range (len(foodprice)):
    fprice = Label(myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = foodprice[x])
    fprice.grid(row = 2+x, column = 8) # <--

for x in range (len(drinks)):
    drinksop = Label(myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = drinks[x])
    drinksop.grid(row = 4+(len(food))+x, column = 4) # <--
for x in range (len(drinksprice)):
    drinksp = Label(myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = drinksprice[x])
    drinksp.grid(row = 4+(len(food))+x, column = 8) # <--
```

Comment: Why not use the `.pack` manager instead of `.grid`. I think it will be much easier to use in this case.

Comment: I just reworked your question to make it more accessible (speaking title, images cropped and embedded, code box without horizontal scrollbars), hopefully without distorting the message. BTW: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please don't forget to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for learning how to successfully interact with the community. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Creating white space around text does not work like in spreadsheet programs.

Tkinter collapses grid rows which are completely empty if there are no weights set by `rowconfigure()` to prevent this. The same is true for columns.

A layout like this:

[image: grid layout with adjacent coordinates]

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def place(col, row, text='Label', color='white'):
    label = tk.Label(root, text=text, bg=color)
    label.grid(column=col, row=row, 
        ipadx=10, ipady=10, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="NSEW")

def make_layout(cols, rows):

    for c in cols:
        place(c, 0, c, 'lightgrey')
        
    for r in rows:
        place(0, r, r, 'lightgrey')

    for r in rows:
        for c in cols:
            place(c, r, 'Label')

make_layout((1,2),(1,2))

root.mainloop()
```

... would look exactly like this:

[image: grid layout with distant coordinates]

without configuring weights in columns `8` to `29` and rows `5` to `49`.

(To get this, replace `make_layout((1,2),(1,2))` by `make_layout((7,30),(4,50))` in code!)

And even if you added weights, Labels are still higher than weighted empty rows, and thus the layout would maybe not look as clean as you might imagine.

[*Tkinter's Grid Geometry Manager*](https://blog.teclado.com/tkinters-grid-geometry-manager/) is a good tutorial I read the other day that goes into this detail. It also introduces the optional `columnspan` and `rowspan` parameters of the `grid()` function.

Last but not least, you should have a look into [*How to justify text in label in Tkinter*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37318060/2932052)